# Specifying Match Repetition for 0 or 4 (not 1, 2, 3)

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I need to specify the regular expression in grep so that it ONLY matches 0 or 4 for the repeating group.

For example,
All the following cases are accepted:

```
Hello,
Hello,abcd
```

But all the following cases are not accepted:

```
Hello,a
Hello,ab
Hello,abc
```

I have tried multiple patterns without success.

```
echo "Hello,a" | grep -E "Hello,[[:alnum:]]{0,4}"`
Hello,a

echo "Hello,12" | grep -E "Hello,[[:alnum:]]{4}?"
Hello,12

echo "Hello,12" | egrep "Hello,([[:alnum:]]{4})?"
Hello,12

echo "Hello,12ab" | grep "Hello,([[:alnum:]]{4})?"
```

The following pattern works but I would like to find an elegant way to do it.

```
$ echo "Hello,123456," | grep -E "Hello,[[:alnum:]]{4},$|Hello,,$"
$ echo "Hello,12345," | grep -E "Hello,[[:alnum:]]{4},$|Hello,,$"
$ echo "Hello,1234," | grep -E "Hello,[[:alnum:]]{4},$|Hello,,$"
Hello,1234,
$ echo "Hello,123," | grep -E "Hello,[[:alnum:]]{4},$|Hello,,$"
$ echo "Hello,12," | grep -E "Hello,[[:alnum:]]{4},$|Hello,,$"
$ echo "Hello,1," | grep -E "Hello,[[:alnum:]]{4},$|Hello,,$"
$ echo "Hello,," | grep -E "Hello,[[:alnum:]]{4},$|Hello,,$"
Hello,,
```

Comment: Have you tried `Hello,([[:alnum:]]{4})?`?

Comment: @LohmarASHAR, I did. It doesn't work for me.

Comment: add `$` at the end of your regex, `grep -E "Hello,[[:alnum:]]{4}?$"`

Comment: Sorry, I was, and still am, on the phone, haven't tested it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat ip.txt
Hello,
Hello,abcd
Hello,a
Hello,ab
Hello,abc

$ grep -xE 'Hello,([[:alnum:]]{4})?' ip.txt 
Hello,
Hello,abcd
```

- `([[:alnum:]]{4})?` would matching nothing or `alnum` characters four times
- `-x` option so that only whole lines are matched. Equivalent to using `grep -E '^Hello,([[:alnum:]]{4})?$'`

Some notes on OP's attempts

```
$ # missing -E option
$ echo "Hello,12ab" | grep 'Hello,([[:alnum:]]{4})?'
$ echo "Hello,12ab" | grep -E 'Hello,([[:alnum:]]{4})?'
Hello,12ab

$ # example when there is trailing ,
$ echo "Hello,1234," | grep -E 'Hello,([[:alnum:]]{4})?,'
Hello,1234,
$ echo "Hello,," | grep -E 'Hello,([[:alnum:]]{4})?,'
Hello,,
```

Answer (score 1):

Use @Sundeeps answer if you only want zero or some other single number of repetitions, otherwise you can use awk for a general solution to the problem of finding specific number(s) of repetitions.

e.g. with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match to check for 12, 17, or 53 chars after `Hello,`:

```
awk 'match($0,/Hello,([[:alnum:]]*)/,a) && length(a[1]) ~ /^(12|17|53)$/'
```

and note that to check for some number other than 12, 17, or 53 is just a simple negation of the comparison:

```
awk 'match($0,/Hello,([[:alnum:]]*)/,a) && length(a[1]) !~ /^(12|17|53)$/'
```

When applied to your original problem:

```
$ cat file
Hello,
Hello,abcd
Hello,a
Hello,ab
Hello,abc
Hello,123456,
Hello,12345,
Hello,1234,
Hello,123,
Hello,12,
Hello,1,
Hello,,
```

.

```
$ awk 'match($0,/Hello,([[:alnum:]]*)/,a) && length(a[1]) ~ /^(0|4)$/' file
Hello,
Hello,abcd
Hello,1234,
Hello,,

$ awk 'match($0,/Hello,([[:alnum:]]*)/,a) && length(a[1]) !~ /^(0|4)$/' file
Hello,a
Hello,ab
Hello,abc
Hello,123456,
Hello,12345,
Hello,123,
Hello,12,
Hello,1,

$ awk 'match($0,/Hello,([[:alnum:]]*)/,a) && length(a[1]) ~ /^(1|3|5)$/' file
Hello,a
Hello,abc
Hello,12345,
Hello,123,
Hello,1,
```